# remove repeated elements from result using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to find a word in array. so i have two arrays

```
 array1 = array ('This is my first array','This is my second element');
 array2= array('This','element')
```

I would like to know the reference of array1 where the words in array 2 match.Following code works fine but it repeats the reference no:

```
 foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    foreach($array2 as $keys => $word) {
    if(strpos($value, $word) !== false) {
            echo $key, PHP_EOL;
        }
    } 
}
```

The result comes as  "0 0 1 1" while i want "0 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case in particular, `break;` will do what you want:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    foreach($array2 as $keys => $word) {
        if(strpos($value, $word) !== false) {
            echo $key, PHP_EOL;
            break; /*Moves on to next array item in array1 instead of looking for
                     more matches in array2*/
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `array_unique` to filter out dupes.

```
$temp_array = array();

if(strpos($value, $word) !== false) {
    $temp_array[] = $key;
}

print implode(' ', array_unique($key));
```

Comment: is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Well I suppose you could store each variable in an array and then check to see if the value appears in the array using `in_array` and then storing the value if it does not appear, but that would be even more work than using `array_unique`.

Comment: You seem to be using `array_unique()` on an integer value.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right.  This was a stupid answer for what he was trying to do.  The accepted answer of `break` was clearly the right answer here.